# How the parens work?

Tags: javascript, function

I have found a piece of code in my teacher s notes and I do not understand it. 
The point is to find the value for "pass" for which the function would return TRUE. 
Can you please answer to my questions below(comments), so I can understand how this works?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function findPassword(pass)
{
    var b = 1337

//How is this function returning "min" (without the parens?)

function add(x){
    b += 84
    return min
}

//Same question as above...for "mod" - how is this compiling? 

function min(x){
    b -= 123
    return mod
}

function div(x){
    b /= 3
    return min
}

function mod(x){
    b = b+5+(b%3)
    return add
}

//what is the purpose of "fn" if it is not used at all?

var fn = function ()
{
    b += 34
    return div
}

//WHAT is happening here? "() () ()"

    (function (){
        b /= 3
        return mod
    })()()()

    if(pass == b*b) { 
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Wrong password !")
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's a chain of functions that return other functions. Every application of the `()` operator calls the function returned by the last function called.

Comment: `How is this function returning "min" (without the parens?)` It's returning the function itself, not the result of invoking the function. You can do this in javascript because functions are first-class citizens

Comment: So it would divide "b by 3 " 3 times?

Comment: Nope. The first function in the chain (the anonymous one) only runs once.

Comment: @StuartLC, it works indeed

Comment: @Lulu: Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/jg9tkqy0/1/

Comment: Why did you completely change the code? This new code throws a TypeError, because, again, the var is missing a semicolon to close it, but in this case, the var is not a function, and 9 cannot be executed (the next anonymous function tries to do so).

Comment: You appear to have completely changed the question, so I rolled it back to the original so that the answers and comments you have so far will continue to make sense. If you have another question, please click "Ask Question" and ask another question. if it's related to this one, feel free to include a link back to this question.

Answer (score 5):

So looking at this:

```
(function (){
    b /= 3
    return mod
})()()()
```

You have this:

```
function (){
    b /= 3
    return mod
}
```

Which is a function. You wrap it in brackets and then call it with `()`, this is called a *immediately invoked function expression* (IIFE).

So what does it return? It returns `mod`, which is a function, so the next `()` will call that function.

What does `mod` return:

```
function mod(x){
    b = b+5+(b%3)
    return add
}
```

It returns the function `add`, which you invoke again with `()`. The function `add` happens to return the function `min`, but since we have no more `()`, we don't invoke it, so it's basically thrown away.

Now, none of this is to suggest this is a *good* way to structure your code, because it isn't.

As for what value will actually make `findPassword` return true? Well, you could follow what happens to `b` in each function.

...or, you could just stick a `console.log(b);` right after the IIFE to see it's value. The value of `pass` you need will be that number squared.

Answer (score 4):

**Just because nobody pointed out what the purpose of the function `fn` in this example is:**

At first sight, it may seem that you've got an anonymous function self executing, and starting a chain of execution by doing so, however, that encapsulated anonymous function, and `add`, are actually the only functions in the code that don't execute, and that is because the declaration of `fn`, before it, is **missing a semicolon**:

```
var fn = function ()
{
    b += 34
    return div
} // <- missing semicolon.
  // Because of this, the `var` statement doesn't stop in here.
```

Because of that missing semicolon, the parentheses encapsulating the anonymous function that comes after this function declaration, are actually executing `fn`, and passing the anonymous function as an argument to it (and `fn` is doing nothing with that argument). **So, in reality, the code looks like this:**

```
var fn = function ()
{
    console.log(arguments[0]); // Logs the anonymous function
    b += 34
    return div
}(function (){
  b /= 3
  return mod
})()()()
// The parentheses () mean 'execute' this.
// If they are chained, they execute what the previous
// function returned.
// It is possible to do that when, like in this code, the functions
// return a function reference (meaning, the name of a function).
```

**Which is pretty much the same as this:**

```
var fn = function () {
    b += 34/= 3
    return div
}( /* Executing fn... */ )( /* div */ )( /* min */ )( /* mod */ )

// fn ends up containing a reference to add, because mod returns that,
// but add is never called.

console.log(fn === add); // true
```

**The chain of execution is this:**

```
fn => div => min => mod
```

**So, to arrive at the password, you do:**

```
var b = 1337;
b += 34;
b /= 3;
b -= 123;
b = b + 5 + (b%3);
// b === 340
// password is b^2: 340 * 340 = 115600
```

Of course, you can also `console.log` *b*, but what's the sense of that?

Comment: Grrr...you are absolutely right of course. Also, the OP should find another teacher because this one is *really* bad. Anybody who writes code like that should not be the person you learn from.

Comment: Unless he/she was trying to teach them to confuse someone trying to decipher how passwords are stored. It's still a bad example and shoulda probably gone for safer encryption but yes, likely that it was a terrible example

Comment: Haha, I just thought they were teaching them about the parentheses syntax and the importance of the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the return statements and you'll see that they are functions, therefore adding `()` to that return value will evaluate it.

The first set of parens executes the function immediately before it. This returns `mod` which is a function. It gets executed by the second parens. This (`mod`) returns `add` which is, again, a function. So the last set of parens executes `add`. Which, in the end, returns `min`.

It's not very clear the way this program is running but it's essentially modifying that one variable and returning more functions to simulate some logic that modifies the variable in different ways depending on how you call the functions.

Comment: So min returns mod, which returns add, which returns min. Isn't it an infinite loop?

Comment: @Lulu, it may appear so, but `min()` is never called. You would need an infinite number of `()`s to actually make this an infinite loop (actually an infinite series of calls, leading to a stack overflow).

Comment: Right, it never calls that last function so it will stop after returning `min` and then do nothing else